# How can I send a request with the mobile data interface when on wifi?

Tags: java, android, mobile, kotlin, wifi

I'm developing an app that has to make all network requests via mobile data, even when it's connected to wifi. The problem is that Android turns off mobile data when connected to wifi for obvious reasons.

I tried to list all the network interfaces so I could use the right one but, when on wifi, the rmnet0 interface even disappears from the list (on a Samsung S8, at least. I tried with a OnePlus and it didn't disappear, but it's not up).

Is there a way to do that, either with Kotlin or using the NDK (C/C++)?

Comment: there is no way AFAIK. You are not the one who can decide which network to use for requests. **WHY?**: The re is at least one reason: imagine the user is in roaming in another country. His mobile data traffic is amazingly expencive. He is connected to a free WIFI, and here comes your app, which does the request through paid mobile network. Don't you find it obvious that you should not be able to waste user's money?

Comment: I know that it's not practical or right to do it, but in the context I'm working in it really has to work like that because I won't be able to get a proper response if I make the requests via wifi.

Comment: Android does not care off the context, you are working in. That's why there is no way to do it directly. Only thing that you can do is to ask user to switch to mobile network when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is disable wifi. That can be done [programmatically in Android](http://androidpermissions.org/android-permission-CHANGE_WIFI_STATE/), provided you have the `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` permission.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(isWifiEnabled);
```

With wifi disabled the phone should switch back to mobile data. As already stated in the comments, that could lead to extra costs for the users and you may want to try to improve the response for wifi instead.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that because it defeats the purpose of having a seamless action for the user, but thank you for the suggestion.